# How to center Simplegrid CSS grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to center generated charts inside a Simplegrid row. I have tried to use align but it doesn't seem to work.

Could someone please guide me on how I can make sure the columns are centered on my page and evenly spaced?

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lightweight-simple-grid@0.0.1/simplegrid.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>


<style>#animationInterface {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.progressBar {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.inline-div {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>

<div align="center">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <!-- This content will take up 3/12 (or 1/4) of the container -->
        <div id='graph_2axBfTGnAR' class='graph'></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <!-- This content will take up 3/12 (or 1/4) of the container -->
        <div id='graph_2axBfTGn' class='graph'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
 var traces_2axBfTGnAR = [{"name":"HI7aZXkts8","type":"heatmap","x":["a","b","c","d","e","f"],"y":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],"z":[[8.83,8.89,8.81,8.87,8.9,8.87],[8.89,8.94,8.85,8.94,8.96,8.92],[8.84,8.9,8.82,8.92,8.93,8.91],[8.79,8.85,8.79,8.9,8.94,8.92],[8.79,8.88,8.81,8.9,8.95,8.92],[8.8,8.82,8.78,8.91,8.94,8.92],[8.75,8.78,8.77,8.91,8.95,8.92],[8.8,8.8,8.77,8.91,8.95,8.94],[8.74,8.81,8.76,8.93,8.98,8.99],[8.89,8.99,8.92,9.1,9.13,9.11],[8.97,8.97,8.91,9.09,9.11,9.11],[9.04,9.08,9.05,9.25,9.28,9.27],[9,9.01,9,9.2,9.23,9.2],[8.99,8.99,8.98,9.18,9.2,9.19],[8.93,8.97,8.97,9.18,9.2,9.18]]}];
 var layout_2axBfTGnAR = {"height":400,"width":500,"hovermode":"closest","title":{"text":"XYZ.HeatmapWithXY"},"showlegend":false};
 var config_2axBfTGnAR = {"responsive":true,"scrollZoom":true,"displaylogo":false};
 Plotly.newPlot("graph_2axBfTGnAR", traces_2axBfTGnAR, layout_2axBfTGnAR, config_2axBfTGnAR);
 Plotly.newPlot("graph_2axBfTGn", traces_2axBfTGnAR, layout_2axBfTGnAR, config_2axBfTGnAR);
</script>
```

Codepen link for runnable example:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/fkE3/pen/LYGgQpg?editors=0010)

I have been stuck on this for a bit of time now, so any solution is much appreciated!!